# MySQL minimum records to add up to 10000

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with two columns: `takenOn`(datetime), and `count`(int). `count` contains the number of steps I have taken.

I'm trying to write a query that will tell me the time when I meet my goal of 10,000 steps every day.

So far, I have the following query:

```
SET @runningTotal=0;
SELECT
    `Date`,
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(takenOn), '%l:%i %p') AS `Time`,
    TotalCount
FROM
    (SELECT
        DATE(s.takenOn) AS `Date`,
        s.takenOn,
        s.`count`,
        @runningTotal := @runningTotal + s.`count` AS TotalCount
    FROM 
    (select * from step where DATE(takenOn) = '2016-10-29') s) temp
WHERE TotalCount >= 10000;
```

This works, but of course gives me the `MIN(takenOn)` for October 29th only. How can I expand this query to give me `MIN(takenOn)` for all possible dates in the table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the steps you care about are all within one day.  You are on the right track.  Here is the code for multiple days:

```
SELECT `Date`, DATE_FORMAT(MIN(takenOn), '%l:%i %p') AS `Time`,
       MIN(TotalCount)
FROM (SELECT DATE(s.takenOn) AS `Date`,
             s.takenOn,
             s.`count`,
             (@runningTotal := if(@d = DATE(s.takenOn), @runningTotal + s.`count`,
                                  if(@d := DATE(s.takeOn), s.`count`, s.`count`)
                                  )
             ) AS TotalCount
      FROM step s CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @runningTotal := 0, @d = '') params
      ORDER BY takenOn
     ) s
WHERE TotalCount >= 10000
GROUP BY `Date`;
```

Note that all the variable assignments are in one expression.  This is important because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.  So, if you split the assignments across more than one expression, you are not guaranteed that the code will work.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I just had to add GROUP BY `Date`. :)

Comment: @CheekuJee . . . You should also use `MIN(TotalCount)` if you want the smallest value that matches your condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Group By and Having clause to achieve this, refer to [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0e79/14):

```
SELECT
  sum(takenON),date
FROM
  step
GROUP BY
  day(date)
Having SUM(takenON)>150
```